# Can admin-ajax.php be used for spam purposes? And if yes, how to prevent that?

Tags: wp-admin, ajax, spam

Today I've got a letter from my hosting provider that admin-ajax.php script had been sending spam until it was blocked. About two thousand spam messages were sent to different emails.
I know if you have proper mail function in your functions.php you can simply run the next code from Google Chrome console:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: { action: 'mail_function', message: 'test'},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Is there another way to do it and any suggestions where I may find vulnerability?

---

I am using ContactForm7 plugin for userforms

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running? I don't see mail_function being a standard action in 3.6 Could you search your code and see if you can find where the code for this is. My bet is in a bad plugin as s_ha_dum said in his answer.

Comment: 3.6 version. 'mail_function' is just an example function that could be used by hackers. But I didn't found even a standard php mail function in my theme.

Comment: Based on the answers you have been given and the wording of your question I have no idea what your asking.  Stop being hypothetical and just ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

## This is why you use nonces.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: { action: 'mail_function', message: 'test', _nonce: <?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'mail_function_' . $post->ID ) ?>},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
```

Then in your PHP function:

```
function my_ajax_mailer() {
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_nonce'], 'mail_function_' . $post->ID ) )
        return;
    // send mail...
}
```

Comment: I don't have mail_function so don't use nonces, Contact Form 7 plugin is enough for my goals

Comment: Well then you have been hacked.

Comment: No, ContactForm7 plugin out of a box generates nonce field `<input type="hidden" value="2a37a6adb1" name="_wpnonce"></input>`

Answer (score 0):

`admin-ajax.php` by itself should not be a problem, but a poorly written function hooked to into the AJAX API could be trouble. I suspect that is what you've got. Your "proper mail function" isn't really as proper as you think and it is happily sending any email from any source.

Or your site has been hacked at some deeper level or you've got a rouge plugin installed. Based on the information provided, it is hard to say.

Comment: 'mail_function' is just an example of hooked function, not presenting in the functions.php. I searched through theme files by "mail" and "eval" keywords and didn't get anything similar.